# Django 3. Не могу перенести сайт. No such table

Tags: python, django

Написал приложение. Добавил в `.gitignore` папки - `__pycache__`, `migrations`.

После чего пытался сделать перенос сайта на хостинг. Выходит ошибка `no such table`.

Попробовал локально поработать, перенес в другую папку сайт. Создал `venv`. Использовал [источник](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html), где говорится как удалить миграции. Также вручную удалил `__pycache__`.

Выдает туже ошибку.

При запуске `migrate` и `makemigrations`. Также выдает ошибку.

Только если закомментировать приложения в `INSTALLED_APPS`. Можно сделать `runserver`, а также сделать `migrate` и `makemigations`.

Comment: А вы на хостинге миграции запускали-то?

Comment: `python manage.py migrate` делали?

Comment: Выдает ту же ошибку при  `migrate` и `makemigrations`. В этом и подвох. Сейчас допишу, что делал.

Comment: Я не знаю как это работает. Задаю вопрос на stackoverflow, сам нахожу ответы. Создал папку utils. В которой были взаимодействия с повторяющимися действиями с БД. Там также была папка `__pycache__`. Удалил ее и все заработало. Не думал, что там также будут фиксации.

Answer (score -1):

Не надо добавлять migrations в .gitignore. Там хранятся скрипты для всех миграций.

Comment: При переносе, я базу не переносил. То есть локальные данные сделаны для тестов. А на продакшене она была пуста.